# Inject service into a utility Ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Is it possible to access an Ember service from an Ember utility? I can't find much of anything about utilities in the docs. Or about services for that matter.

I'm using Ember-cli 0.2.7 and Ember 1.12.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Ember utility is just a exported JavaScript method, while `Ember.Service` is part of Ember ecosystem. To access `Ember.Service` from utility you would have to pass reference to concrete `Ember.Service` to utility which is probably bad design decision.

If you could explain what do you need utility and service for it would probably be easier to suggest correct way to go, without passing directly reference to `Ember.Service` to JavaScript method.

You can use Ember.Service when you have some logic / states that need to be shared across many controllers / routes. For example, you can define sound service, and then from many places use public methods you will write/expose. You can make sure that only 1 song plays at the moment. That's service for. Utility can be helpful for example to create some async pattern, like specific way of iterating over promises, like `mapSeries` - it is universal and can be used in many places. Thanks to requiring it as utility your code is DRY and you import it where you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wasn't really clear on what the difference was between the 2, or why/how to use them.

I'm working on a mobile hybrid app with Cordova. It uses NFC, which needs to be initialized when the app starts.

In an application initializer instance, I wanted to call an NFC utility method to initialize NFC. But the NFC utility also needs to access a service I have written.

Maybe I can make an NFC service instead of a utility, but I don't know how to access that in the initializer instance.

Comment: You can access service in initializer using container lookup service:nfc